# Авторизация root'а в PMA на Ubuntu 16.04 под LAMP

Tags: php, ubuntu, phpmyadmin, lamp

Установил по отдельности пакеты LAMP'a. Проблема в авторизации в PHPMyAdmin.
Когда устанавливал mysql - пароль не вводил, всегда нажимал OK во время инсталяции. Через консоль могу войти без пароля следующим образом:

```
sudo mysql -u root -p
```

А затем при запросе пароля просто жму Enter и я зашел.

Когда без `sudo` вхожу, пишет:

`ERROR 1698 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'`

В PHPMyAdmin при попытке входа возникает:

`Вход без пароля запрещен при конфигурации (смотрите AllowNoPassword)`

В файле `/etc/phpmyadmin/config.inc.php` изменяю:

`$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = TRUE;`

Но теперь вылетает:

`#1698 - Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'`

В чем проблема, если пароля нет, я его не устанавливаел. Смотрю в таблицу `user.mysql` - там он тоже не проставлен?

Comment: А у вас точно Oracle MySQL? А то вот в Debian его тихо заменили на MariaDB, и в результате какая-то похожая проблема у меня возникала один раз. Решил установкой оригинального MySQL.

Comment: может стоит задать пароль?

Comment: @AlexanderZonov да, oracle

Comment: @rjhdby задал для бд. В phpmyadmin не робит(